# Multiple notifications for the same post should be marked "read" as a group

Tags: bug, feature-request, global-inbox

1. Create some trackable content inside Stack Overflow (e.g., leave a comment on a question)
2. Someone responded with two or more separate comments tagging me
3. I receive two or more notifications that lead to the same page
4. Clicking on the notification marks, read only that one, not all related notifications

I have to click either "mark all as read" (that may mark notifications that are not read yet) or click on each of the messages separately going into the same question page multiple times.

This may be treated as an intended feature, so that you *actually* read the notification, but I think in most other platforms this feature marks all related notifications as read at once.

Comment: To be honest... I'd rather just not have two notifications really. It is such a spammy system that I don't want to be bothered by it in its current state.

Comment: I'd settle for if the notifications were grouped. So you only see the first one and any followup notifications spawned from the same question page just end up as +1, +2, +3, etc. I could live with that.

Comment: @Gimby Or maybe multi-level notifications, where you see question name as group and can expand it to see all related notifications? Obvious it should be as is not for single notification per question.

Comment: I'd like if I didn't have to mark the question as read in my inbox after *going to the corrresponding page* in a new tab. The system knows I've accessed that page, and should thus be able to de-notify me for everything that's associated with it.

Comment: This is tangential at best, but also: that colour scheme? Ewww.