# Not all unread messages sent by the same user appear in the inbox

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

At the beginning the indicator showed there were 2 unread messages, but when I clicked the inbox button I could see just one, and the indicator showed there was 1 message left.

[image: Stage1]

I had to refresh the page, then I could see another one.

[image: Stage2]

Two messages are comments from the same user in the same question. I think this is a bug.

Comment: I have observed a very similar case one or two days ago: two comments posted from the same user, only one appears in the inbox, red indicator about unread messages, but the second message appears only on refreshing the page. Before, all glitches in the inbox was resolvable by the "Refresh" link which appears near "Mark all as read". But that time the link hasn't appeared. Another time, two comments from the same user was truly reported via single inbox message: no red flag, nothing changed on refreshing the page. Probably, time distance between the comments affects the behavior.

Comment: @Makyen: Are you sure that the [referenced question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422381/multiple-notifications-for-the-same-post-should-be-marked-read-as-a-group) is actually about the same problem as the given one? As far as I understand the referenced question, it is about the case when two comments from the same user create two separate notifications which are **correctly displayed** in the INBOX. The other asker *requested* to combine these notifications into one. But the current question is about **incorrect displaying** of these notifications.

Comment: Yes, it's the same bug (feature?) Multiple comment notifications from the same post get rolled into one notification, and clearing it doesn't always clear them all. It's been broken since december.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It's the same issue. If it's actually *identical* depends on what's really happening, which isn't clear from the descriptions, but it's the same underlying issue of merging inbox entries and not marking entries read when clicking on one that leads to the same post/comment section.

Comment: The underlying issue has been reported probably 20 or 30 times on MSO, MSE, and chat, including in at least the following in answers to [Inbox improvements are live](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/) The following answers on that question are related to this issue: [384162](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/384162), [384189](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/384189), [384212](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/384212), [384310](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/384310), [385543](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/385543), and [384211](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/384211).

Comment: There are multiple related comments on that question and answers, but of particular note is [this comment](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live/384212#comment1281411_384212)

Comment: @KevinB: "Yes, it's the same bug (feature?)" - I always thought that a *feature* can never be same(duplicate) as a *bug*. It looks like SE developers have started to implement the *feature*, and in result we observe the *bug*. Among the referenced answers from MSE, I have found the only one which *resembles* the given bug: [384310](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live/384310#384310). But it describes that reopening the INBOX ("When I close and open the inbox") solves the glitch. I am pretty confident that I have tried that in my case and it didn't help.

Comment: Well, I have nothing against the duplicate mark if it will be a single change (or changeset) which make solved both the feature and the bug(s). I just worry that some time SE devs will treat the feature to be already implemented but do not fix the bug(s).